# Google pytrends in Python jupyter notebook

Tags: google-trends

I am trying to run a script in jupyter notebook but getting a connection error

here is my script

```py
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import requests
#make a pytrends object to request Google Trends data
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US') 
#extract data about weekly searches of certain keywords
keywords = ["Python", "R", "C++", "Java", "HTML"]
pytrends.build_payload(keywords, timeframe='today 5-y')
```

and my error is

ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='trends.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?geo=US (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001605F2C53C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))

Comment: proxy error is now gone because I have used proxy parameter in TrendReq() function but now I am getting time out error.   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='trends.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?geo=GB (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002122774A588>, 'Connection to 192.168.1.5 timed out. (connect timeout=2)'))